# Alterar formato da data comando batch

Tags: batch, bat

Estou criando um script em .bat para copiar os arquivos que forem adicionados no dia atual em determinada pasta.

```
set caminhoOrigem="pasta1"
set caminhoDestino="pasta2"
set dataAtual=%DATE%
xcopy %caminhoOrigem% %caminhoDestino% /D:%dataAtual%
```

Porém o `xcopy` só funciona com data no formato MM-DD-AAAA, como faço para alterar o formato visualização do `%DATE%`, que fica no padrão DD/MM/AAAA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode utilizar o **for** para manipular o valor de **%date%**
antes de jogar o valor dela para o **xcopy**, desta forma.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%A in ("%date%") do (set data=%%B-%%A-%%C)
```

exibindo o valor da variável **%data%**, vai sair este resultado:

```
mes-dia-ano
```

em **tokens=** eu utilizei o valor 1,2,3
mas você pode substituir por um asterisco, já que vai utilizar
todos os valores da string a ser manipulada, sendo: 1 para o dia, 2 para o mês e 3 para o ano.

**%%A** representa o dia, **%%B** representa o mês e **%%C** representa o ano.
por isso ficou: **set data=%%B-%%A-%%C**

Answer (score 0):

Não se há resposta melhor, mas funcionou alterar o comando

```
set dataAtual=%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%date:~6,4%
```